# Set text colour in strings started min SDK version 7

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have this line in my code.

```
String credit= "<font color='#0166b9'>Credit: </font>";
```

I need to get "Credit: " string from my resources, because It can change depended of device default language. So how I can use value of some variable in this line ?

**EDIT:**

I must have only one word or some text coloured. It means that I must have different coloured TextView.

There is some way to set colour in your R.strings , here is the example

```
<string name="clients_credit"> <font fgcolor="#0166b9">Credit: </font> </string>
```

But it works only for latest versions. So it'll be great to find some way to setting colour in string.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is it.

```
TextView debitTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewclientDebit);
final Spannable clientsDebit= new SpannableString(mContext.getString(R.string.clients_debit));
clientsDebit.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)), 0, clientsDebit.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
debitTxtView.setText(clientsDebit);
debitTxtView.append(" " + file.getDebit());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use Html.fromHtml();

You can define your string in string.xml as

```
<string name="title"><![CDATA[<font color='#0166b9'>Credit: </font>]]></string>
```

And in java file you need to use spannable text

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources.getString(R.string.title)), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for Response but I'm getting this error
 error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in <font color='#0166b9'>Credit: </font>)

Comment: change color='#0166b9' by color=\'#0166b9\'

Answer (score 0):

Add Credit: to your `strings` file and then retrieve it later on like `getResources().getString(R.string.credit)` and add colour like `getResources().getColor(R.color.textColour)`. Add

`<color name="textColor">#0166b9</color>`

to your `color` XML in `res` folder. If you don't have one create one.

Comment: Thanks for response but how to add colour for String? My string in resource files I can get it but I don't know how to set colour on it.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find line or command where you are putting colour for text. I know how to work with resources but I need to add some text to TextView with unique colour. And also I have to set it from java code.

Comment: You can add this way thorough Java code `textView.setText(R.string.credit);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColour));`

Comment: But it will change colour of whole text , I need only one word or some part of text.

Comment: So you want to change the color of a substring?

Comment: Yes, I'v add some line that will change my text colour but I need to set string from my R.string.... , I don't know how to use my resource's strings in this line

Comment: If the `String` to be set is a single line you can use multiple `Textview` otherwise no idea. Sorry.

Comment: I thought about that but it is really not good way, there is some way to setting colour in your R.String , so you'll have coloured string but it's work only for latest versions, here is the example. 
<string name="clients_credit"> <font fgcolor="#0166b9">Credit: </font> </string>
I'm suggesting you to follow this question, because some they you'll need to change on word colour in whole description of you app :). Anyway thank you very much for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Textview tV;
// Initialize textview 
tV.setText(R.string.credit);
tV.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_color);
tV.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.text_color));
```

Comment: Thanks for responce but I need to change text color not TextView background colour

Comment: My apologies. I edited my answer to show you how to achieve that as well ;)

Comment: Thanks again but I need to change only one word in TextView , not all text :(

Comment: This is not possible via xml resources. You could use Html.fromHtml.

Answer (score 0):

Put file named colors.xml under res/values of your Android project.

Declare the color in that file

```
<color name="myColor">#ff0166b9<color>
```

Declare the string in strings.xml under res/values

```
<string name="credit">"Credit: "</string>
```

In your Activity, get reference to TextView defined in activity layout using the

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);
```

and then use the following to set the string and text color.

```
textView.setText(R.string.credit);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response but I need to set colour only one word , nor whole text in TextView.

Comment: You can either use to separate TextViews or build an HTML and set it to TextView. Let me build an example.